# How to print function calls and backtrace in the toplevel?

Tags: function, debugging, ocaml, ocaml-toplevel

I'm trying to get the backtrace of function calls. I wonder if anyone knows how to do that in the toplevel.

Answer (score 4):

[`#trace`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/toplevel.html#sec256) directive is useful to trace functions, e.g.,

```
# let rec f x = if x > 0 then f (x - 1) else "done";;
val f : int -> string = <fun>
# #trace f;;
f is now traced.
# f 12;;
f <-- 12
f <-- 11
f <-- 10
...
```

To trace several functions, use #trace for all of them, e.g.,

```
#trace f;;
#trace g;;
```

Do not forget, that after you redefined a function, you need to invoke `#trace` again, since from the toplevel perspective this is a new function, although it has the same name.

To untrace function `f` use `#untrace f`, to untrace all functions, that are currently traced use `#untrace_all`

Also, you may find useful `Printexc.get_callstack` function, that, if you enabled trace recording with `Printexc.record_bactrace true`, will show you current call stack.